# Redirect http to https, port 80 being used by other service

Tags: http, https, apache2, redirect, virtualhost

I have apache (httpd) serving my site, with SSL enabled (on https, port 443).

Also, on the same server, I have a separate process, which is using port 80. Now, I want to redirect my site, if it is requested on plain http to be redirected to https. Of course, apache's configuration doesn't help, as it is not serving on port 80. Please help with the possible solutions for this!!

Comment: What software is the other process? Any way to configure it like a webserver?

Comment: 2 processes generally cannot bind the same port. Maybe you need to bind your custom process on another port and use Apache on port 80 as reverse proxy.

Comment: @TobiasK No. Its not a web server. Its a simple php program serving static web pages, but it has to run on 80.

Comment: You could in PHP check if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is your other site and then return the redirect there (using `header('Location: ...')`). Binding a PHP standalone server process on port 80 rather than a dedicated webserver seems questionable though. Your content could still be accessed on 80 when you let Apache proxy it.

Comment: Please clarify, is this really a PHP process (started with [`php -S 0.0.0.0:80`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)) or just a PHP script running in Apache?

Comment: Separate php process, not involving apache

Comment: @TobiasK I could have proxied it through apache, but I only have "rights" to change my configurations. Owner of other (php) process has totally restricted me from doing anything to his stuff. :/

Comment: Then putting a routine that checks the `Host` header and issues the redirect (see comment above) at the top of your PHP script (`else` your unchanged script) is the only way I can think of. Do you get the idea of shall I write a more extensive answer with a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer based on the comments below questions (not able to modify Apache-conf, standalone PHP process)*

Assuming you have the following script `staticpageserver.php` running via `php -S 0.0.0.0:80 staticpageserver.php` ([Built-in web server](http://php.net/commandline.webserver)):

```php
<?php
#staticpageserver.php

// Your PHP / static content logic below here
echo 'Some content';
```

to serve your content on port 80. For one domain only (example: *your.page.com*) you now want to redirect to port 443 / HTTPS. 
This could be achieved by checking the *Host*-header and redirecting in PHP, at the top of your script:

```php
<?php
#staticpageserver.php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'your.page.com') {
    http_response_code(302); // 302 Found Redirect. Maybe use 301 instead.
    header('Location: https://your.page.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit; // Do not execute further than the redirect
}

// Your PHP / static content logic below here
echo 'Some content';
```

For any other access (another domain, directly via IP adress) than that domain you still run through your script.

Comment: This seems ok. Although, would this provide security equivalent to apache configuration?

Comment: What kind of security are you concerned about? `$_SERVER` generally shouldn't be trusted, as the user can modify it, but we're not writing it anywhere (DB, `exec`) except the Location header for the same user.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .htaccess to redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Would this do only for my domain? Or all requests on http? (I think I'm asking a silly question here, but just to confirm :|)

Comment: This does not help!! Now that I think of, how will any config in htaccess help. This configuration would never run. The index page from other service pops up.